# wordpress installation HTTP request failure

Tags: php, wordpress

I just installed wordpress on my domain and to install themes, plugins, or even import a blog it gives the following error:

```
An Unexpected HTTP Error occurred during the API request.
```

What could be causing this? It's terribly annoying since I want to import my blogger blog.

EDIT: workarounds for themes and plugins are to manually download and upload via FTP but that's just ridiculous.

Comment: Ridiculous? For the first 5 years of WordPress, where it grew to over 30 million active blogs, that was the ONLY way to install themes or plugins. The new thing where it will install from a URL or link is.. pretty new. This question belongs on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com btw.

Comment: I've grown used to it ever since it became a feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common reason for this error is that a request made timed out. If you put your error message in quotes and search for it on Google you'll find lots of information.

Comment: thank you so much! was a timeout error.